# OnRenderSurfaceBaseLoaded null exception when connecting using Windows Remote Desktop

Tags: wpf, windows, scichart

OnRenderSurfaceBaseLoaded null exception when connecting using Windows Remote Desktop. Tested on SciChart 4.2.3.10193 and v5.1.0.11299 on Windows 10. There's a related post in the following but doesn't resolve this issue on SciChart  v5.1.0.11299

https://www.scichart.com/questions/question/nullreferenceexception-when-using-direct3d

```
Exception 1: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
at SciChart.Drawing.DirectX.Context.D3D10.Direct3D10RenderSurface.OnRenderSurfaceBaseLoaded(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised) 
at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args) 
at System.Windows.BroadcastEventHelper.BroadcastEvent(DependencyObject root, RoutedEvent routedEvent) 
at System.Windows.BroadcastEventHelper.BroadcastLoadedEvent(Object root) at MS.Internal.LoadedOrUnloadedOperation.DoWork() 
at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.FireLoadedPendingCallbacks() at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.FireInvokeOnRenderCallbacks() at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandlerCore(Object resizedCompositionTarget) 
at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandler(Object resizedCompositionTarget) 
at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs) 
at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
```

Changes we made includes calling IRenderSurface.Dispose() to release memory usage originated from CustomRenderableSeries with LinearGradient Brush

`if(scs.GetValue(SciChartSurfaceBase.RenderSurfaceProperty) is IRenderSurface renderSurface)
   renderSurface.Dispose();`

Comment: Hi Noah, i cannot reproduce this crash in scichart examples over RDP using latest version. Perhaps submit a bug report with code to repro to scichart's support?

Answer (score 1):

According to [SciChart's website](https://www.scichart.com/scichart-wpf-directx-compatibility/), remote desktop should be supported without any crashes.

> **Q: Does the DirectX Renderer Work over Remote Desktop?**
>
> A: We use D3DImage, which is a Microsoft control that allows sharing of DirectX
>   content with WPF, avoiding airspace issues and allowing fast interop
>   between WPF’s DirectX9 and DirectX10 rendering.
>
> Unfortunately D3DImage has a bug, a nasty one. It won’t work over
>   remote desktop if your application is .NET4.0! It will work over
>   Remote Desktop on .NET4.5 and above.
>
> Since SciChart v4 we have developed a workaround where SciChart
>   DirectX will now work over remote desktop. This is automatic and no
>   changes need to be applied to your code.

I would suggest if the problem still occurs in the latest version ([checking latest nightly from NuGet](https://support.scichart.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/17232/37/getting-nightly-builds-with-nuget)) to package up code to reproduce and send it to [tech support](http://support.scichart.com/index.php?/Tickets/Submit).

Comment: Andrew,Thank you for the response! Is D3DImage memory leak issge resolved in DirectX11? If it is fixed, our code doesn't have to call IRenderSurface.Dispose(); to clear the memory, which seems to trigger the D3DImage null exception.

Comment: I'm not aware of memory leak in D3DImage itself, but the SciChart property Direct3D11RenderSurface.UseAlternativeFillSource bypasses D3DImage entirely (used for compatibility on some computer hardware) if that class is a problem for you.